# How do I make single quote function like a double quote in octave mode?

Tags: syntax-table, octave

I'm using octave mode for matlab which works great mostly. However, now I've run into a difference in quoting mechanisms between matlab and octave which makes emacs misinterpret the code and mess up indentation.
I'm searching for the first left parenthesis in a string:

```
startind=find(s=='(',1);
```

The characters in between the single quotes are not escaped, which makes emacs expect a closing right parenthesis. The right parenthesis doesn't show up and the indentation and syntax highlighting of the rest of the file is off.
I tried adding:

```
(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook
(lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?\' "\"")))
```

but it makes no difference.
I also checked the syntax class of single quote after reloading my init file by evaluating the line below with C-x C-e:

```
(char-to-string (char-syntax ?\'))
```

which returns:

```
"."
```

And I also checked the syntax class of double quote:

```
(char-to-string (char-syntax ?\"))
```

which returns:

```
"\""
```

What am I missing here? I'm a copy-paster when it comes to elisp and would be grateful for help.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Ok, thanks for info!